# SAP Business Objects 3.1 XI problems on regenerate structure

Tags: oracle, structure, business-objects

I have problems to refresh the structure of a table in my universe.
We have added some data to a reference table which is used in universe. After checking the new data in (Oracle 11g) database, found everything OK.
Then opened up designer in BO, imported the universe, looked up the associated table which only shows the existing items (not the new ones) - which seemed ok for me. I clicked on "View"/"Regenerate structure" but BO says that the structure does not need to be regenerated?

I have no idea what goes wrong and how I can add the new items to the table in my universe. Or do I have to update the content of a table differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that Designer isn't properly reading the database's data dictionary, and therefore not seeing the new column.

Data fields do not **have** to be present in the model in Designer in order for objects to reference them.  So I would create a new universe object that references one of the new fields, and parse it.  If it parses, then the field really is there and Designer just isn't seeing it.  However if it doesn't work (i.e., you get an "invalid identifier"-type error), then the field is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer gave me the hint to check again why the new fields have not been there. And finally I found it. My "table" was a view which had to be actualized (SQL-select statement) and after that I could pick up the data into my universe and as shown in reports. Now everything is fine.

Comment: To accept an answer, please click on the tick/check icon to the left of the answer you prefer, until it turns green.